# Customizing a library class in QT

Tags: qt, class, customization, paint

I would like to create a specific `QPlainTextEditor` in Qt. Namely, I would like to highlight every second row with grey. Now, I've made a new `QAbstractScrollArea` class (`HighlightedOddLineScrollArea`) and I've modified its `paintEvent`, but I've no idea how to implement it into my text editor. Do I have to do it through a constructor, or is there a function to exchange the default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to subclass QPlainTextEditor and reimplement its paintEvent function. Since the function is virtual the one that you define will be called instead of the parent class'